# Jest Test Failed - TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I try to make a snapshot testing using react-test-renderer, I need to render a component which use the code below (in a separate file) to conditionally render different component.

```html
let mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");
let mobileView = mql.matches;
export default mobileView;
```

This is the snapshot test

```html
test("Your test case", () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<CalendarTitle month={8} year={2021} />);
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I have tried using jest-matchmedia-mock package but it can't solve the problem, maybe it need to mock in a different file but i am not sure what to write in matchMedia.mock.ts file and what is the myMethod from "file-to-test" and how to write to complete test method.

```html
import matchMedia from './matchMedia.mock.ts'; // Must be imported before the tested file
import { myMethod } from './file-to-test';

describe('myMethod()', () => {
  // Test the method here...
});
```